# Is there any way to force Maven to only build shaded jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, minecraft

I code Minecraft plugins and in this specific one I am using some dependencies.

When I click Run (I think it's set to package clean in the IntelliJ config), I want it to build the shaded one. Right now, it builds the unshaded one, then if I click run again it builds the shaded one. Is there any way to only build the shaded one, or make my Minecraft server prioritize Shaded > Original?

Thanks!

pom.xml: https://paste.md-5.net/xutirixepo.xml

Comment: You need to show your Maven configuration. You can find it in a file called `pom.xml` in the project root directory.

Comment: @McPringle https://pastebin.com/3iBJuzXi Here's my entire pom

Comment: Never use system dependent directories nor directories outside your current directory in your configuration. The building on command line can be done by `mvn clean package` als in IDEA IntelliJ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mvn clean package` from the IDE terminal or from Maven tool window in IDE `clean` and then `package` goals as per maven-shade-plugin documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html You can add these maven goals to be executed [**Before launch** in your run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_before_run) in IDE:

[image]

[image]